# "Referer Header Required" error in couchdb when trying to use _find

Tags: macos, curl, couchdb

I'm getting started with CouchDB, and have started building an application. I can write and read just fine using CURL, but i've started to try and search, using _find, and i get an error stating "Referer Header Required".

`curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/mydb/_find -d '{"selector":{"member.email":"foo@bar.com"}}`

returns:

`{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Referer header required."}`

When I try and add a "Referer" host in the call, it just says the referer needs to match the host, but I don't know what host it means.

`curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/mydb/_find -d '{"selector":{"member.email":"matthew"}}' -H "Referer: localhost"
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Referer header must match host."}`

I've tried all sorts of combinations, using the localhost, the with and without the port numbers, I've tried with X-Forwarded-Host, I've find a dozen related articles about POST vs PUT, and versioning, but I've come to a dead end, and just can't figure out what I'm missing.

nb. I'm running couchdb1.7.x on an OSX laptop.

Comment: The referer has to be a URL, not just a hostname. You might still get another error after that because I don't think it needs a referer for such a query.

Comment: @EricDarchis i think i tried every possible combination - IP address, hostnames, fully qualified URLs, paths, all sorts.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix the `Referer header required` and the subsequent `Referer header must match host` by looking through the source code. Though the real problem was expecting _find to work in those ancient 1.X builds OS package managers default to. It's much better to upgrade to the latest version of couchdb (3.1.1).

You can workaround the error on old versions by adding vhosts to the config file `/etc/couchdb/local.ini`

```
[vhosts]
;localhost = /db/
localhost = /*
[httpd]
x_forwarded_host = Y-Forwarded-Host
```

and potentially also using a custom header name for X-Forwarded-Host, in my case the software fetching the API call does some overly clever things to X-Forwarded-Host and Host headers.

so when you call couchdb just include the new header with either 'localhost'

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/mydb/_find \
-H 'Referer: localhost' \
-H 'Y-Forwarded-Host: localhost' \
-d '{"selector":{"member.email":"foo@bar.com"}}
```

or blank so they match

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/mydb/_find \
-H 'Referer' \
-H 'X-Forwarded-Host' \
-d '{"selector":{"member.email":"foo@bar.com"}}
```

neither header is needed in version 2 or 3 onward, they came to their senses.

Comment: I don't know if this works but I upvoted your answer because I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

Probaly too late but for for the next people (like me) that will get on this topic, 
the problem is :

```
http://localhost:5984/mydb/_find
```

When you try to change POST in PUT you get the problem :

```
"reason":"Only reserved document ids may start with underscore."
```

the _document refer to special function so just change the name of the document :)

(should work in both post / put after this)

Comment: `find` is a `POST`, not `PUT`, and elicits the error `Referer header required`, not the underscore error. I'm still looking for an answer to the question.