# error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"

Tags: json, couchdb

When I try to import a file json like this:

```bash
curl -d @myfile.json -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://admin:admin123@localhost:5984/test/_bulk_docs
```

content of myfile.json is

```json
{
  "address": {
    "building": "1007",
    "coord": [
      -73.856077,
      40.848447
    ],
    "street": "Morris Park Ave",
    "zipcode": "10462"
  },
  "borough": "Bronx",
  "cuisine": "Bakery",
  "grades": [
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": 1393804800000
      },
      "grade": "A",
      "score": 2
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": 1378857600000
      },
      "grade": "A",
      "score": 6
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": 1358985600000
      },
      "grade": "A",
      "score": 10
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": 1322006400000
      },
      "grade": "A",
      "score": 9
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": 1299715200000
      },
      "grade": "B",
      "score": 14
    }
  ],
  "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop",
  "restaurant_id": "30075445"
}
```

and then an error

> "error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"

How can I fix it or have another way to import a file json to couchDb??

Comment: Post the actual content of `myfile.json`

Comment: @RamblinRose the content of myfile.json is {"address": {"building": "1007", "coord": [-73.856077, 40.848447], "street": "Morris Park Ave", "zipcode": "10462"}, "borough": "Bronx", "cuisine": "Bakery", "grades": [{"date": {"$date": 1393804800000}, "grade": "A", "score": 2}, {"date": {"$date": 1378857600000}, "grade": "A", "score": 6}, {"date": {"$date": 1358985600000}, "grade": "A", "score": 10}, {"date": {"$date": 1322006400000}, "grade": "A", "score": 9}, {"date": {"$date": 1299715200000}, "grade": "B", "score": 14}], "name": "Morris Park Bake Shop", "restaurant_id": "30075445"}

Comment: So you know, it would have been better to edit the original post with that data (formatted) rather than cram it into a comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the content is malformed as [POST /{db}/_bulk_docs](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-docs) wants the data to be in the form of a JSON object with a `docs` array property

```json
{
  "docs": [
    . . .
  ]
}
```

within which as one should guess, the `docs` array should contain one or more documents.

Comment: {"docs":[{"address": {"building": "1007", "coord": [-73.856077, 40.848447], "street": "Morris Park Ave", "zipcode": "10462"}, "borough": "Bronx", "cuisine": "Bakery"]} do it right?

Comment: @Pien that is not valid JSON - you are missing a `}` after "Bakery".  Online JSON validators are all over the web, just search "json validator".

Comment: I added a } after "Bakery" but have an error is {"error":"bad_request","reason":"Referer header required."} :(

Comment: That's a completely different problem. Search and ye shall find, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720537/referer-header-required-error-in-couchdb-when-trying-to-use-find